# Scheduling a release waiting for approval via DevOps API

Tags: api, azure-devops

I need to schedule a release deployment via Azure DevOps' API.

The release is pending approval and via the interface I can schedule the deployment:

[image]

Via the API there is no option for it ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/approvals/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#approvalstatus)).

The only options I have are `approved`, `canceled`, `pending`, `reassigned`, `rejected`, `skipped` or `undefined`.

So I tried to patch the release environment itself ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/update-release-environment?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#environmentstatus)) by changing it to "scheduled":

`PATCH https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/jato-jaas/Services/_apis/Release/releases/{releaseId}/environments/{environmentId}?api-version=6.0-preview.6`

```
{
    "status": "scheduled",
    "scheduledDeploymentTime": "2022-06-28T16:00:00Z",
    "variables": {},
    "comment": "Automated deployment"
}
```

When I call the API I receive this response: `Transitioning of stage from state 'InProgress' to state 'Scheduled' is not allowed.`

How can I schedule a release that is waiting for approval via the API? I know how to "start" a release with a schedule, but this is not what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so, I found the solution.

You need to change the release schedule without changing the status (doesn't make sense, but works).

So, you need to call the release environment patch API (`https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/jato-jaas/Services/_apis/Release/releases/{releaseId}/environments/{environmentId}?api-version=6.0-preview.6`) with a JSON like this:

```
{
    "scheduledDeploymentTime": "2022-06-28T16:00:00Z",
    "comment": "Automated deployment"
}
```

You'll receive a propper `200` response but no mention at all in the response about the scheduled time but if you request information about the release you'll find the scheduled time set in the response.

So, call `GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/jato-jaas/Services/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}?api-version=6.0` and you'll find it in the environment data (`scheduledDeploymentTime`).

[image]

I believe this is exactly what I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45414516/deferred-deployment-with-visual-studio-team-services-approval-api) but for DevOps.

Comment: Looks like you HAVE to have a pre-deployment approval on the stage in order for this to work, I'm getting the error "Make sure you have pending approvals in the stage" We don't want an approval, we just want to override the trigger schedule. So for now we are cancelling the deployment of that stage, scheduling using task scheduler by setting the status: "inProgress". It just looks like you can' t re-schedule or override a trigger schedule in AzDO pipelines.